# Scripting in Applescript - Integer vs Exponential Number Representation

Tags: excel, integer, applescript, exponential

I have code that retrieves cells in an excel file that looks like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"  
-- put the complete set of data into a list of lists (i.e., 2 dimensions -> columns of rows)
set range1 to range "B2:H7686"
tell active sheet to set myData to value of range1
-- now access a specific cell's data
set myRow to 7
set myCol to 3
set myVal to item {myCol} of item {myRow} of myData as string

end tell
```

but when I get the resulting list of lists, numbers that are greater than 10000.0 are represented in exponential form.

How can I either get this script to retrieve the numbers in regular integer form or change the numbers in the lists to integer form after I have run this script?

Side Note: These lists contain both numbers and strings

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript Editor always displays integers with >8 digits and floats with >4 digits before the decimal point in exponential notation.

Here's one way to get a value from the front Excel spreadsheet:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        set x to column 1's row 1's value
    end tell
end tell
```

And here's one way to determine whether or not the value is a string:

```
set isString to ( x's class is equal to text )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to set myData to formula of cells of (range "B2:H7686")
```

Comment: Happy to help. If I answered your question you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so others know the issue has been resolved.